# Convert 128-bit hexadecimal string to base-36 string

Tags: c++

I have a 128-bit number in hexadecimal stored in a string (from md5, security isn't a concern here) that I'd like to convert to a base-36 string.  If it were a 64-bit or less number I'd convert it to a 64-bit integer then use an algorithm I found to convert integers to base-36 strings but this number is too large for that so I'm kind of at a loss for how to approach this.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Edit: After Roland Illig pointed out the hassle of saying 0/O and 1/l over the phone and not gaining much data density over hex I think I may end up staying with hex.  I'm still curious though if there is a relatively simple way to convert an hex string of arbitrary length to a base-36 string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A base-36 encoding requires 6 bits to store each token.  Same as base-64 but not using 28 of the available tokens.  Solving 36^n >= 2^128 yields n >= log(2^128) / log(36) or 25 tokens to encode the value.

A base-64 encoding also requires 6 bits, all possible token values are used.  Solving 64^n >= 2^128 yields n >= log(2^128) / log(64) or 22 tokens to encode the value.

Calculating the base-36 encoding requires dividing by powers of 36.  No easy shortcuts, you need a division algorithm that can work with 128-bit values.  The base-64 encoding is much easier to compute since it is a power of 2.  Just take 6 bits at a time and shift by 6, in total 22 times to consume all 128 bits.

Why do you want to use base-36?  Base-64 encoders are standard.  If you really have a constraint on the token space (you shouldn't, ASCII rulez) then at least use a base-32 encoding.  Or any power of 2, base-16 is hex.

Comment: @eco: If there's a technical restriction limiting you to 36 characters, then you might want to use Base-32 instead.  You'll need to use 26 "digits" instead of 25, but you can use bitshifting.

Comment: The reason for base-36 is so it is easily readable over the phone to humans.  Base-36 would let me use all of the numbers and alphabet which would make it much shorter than just using hexadecimal.

Comment: base-36 encodes a little more than 5 bits per digit, which is not much more than the 4 bits you get by using hex. The risk you are taking is that people confuse 0 with O and 1 with I. I don't think it's worth the effort. You should rather only use the ten decimal digits and print them in groups of four.

Comment: @Roland That's a good point.  I'd rather not deal with 0/O and 1/l and converting it to an unusually represented (no O or L) base-34 would limit the density to almost be not worth it.  I may just stick with hex I suppose.

Comment: Yuck, since when have people ever been able to deal with 22 tokens?  A computer doesn't mind the difference between a 1 and an I or an l.  AT&T proved a long time ago that the human capacity is 7 tokens, 10 if you push it.  The number of digits you dial on a phone to talk to somebody.  There's a level of pragmatism that needs to squeak into this question.  Hashes are for machines, not people.

Comment: I had actually planned to truncate it to 16 (4 groups of 4).  I don't really need 16 even and I'd consider taking it down even further if it weren't for the fact that it needs to be uniform with another system we already have in place that uses 16.  Thinking about this makes me realize even more so that hex should suffice.

Comment: Regarding I/1 and O/0, just omit all four and you have 32 characters left to do a tidy base-32 encoding without these pain points.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing that is missing is the support for 128 bit unsigned integers, here is the solution for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
        uint32_t v3, v2, v1, v0;
} uint128;

static void
uint128_divmod(uint128 *out_div, uint32_t *out_mod, const uint128 *in_num, uint32_t in_den)
{
        uint64_t x = 0;

        x = (x << 32) + in_num->v3;
        out_div->v3 = x / in_den;
        x %= in_den;
        x = (x << 32) + in_num->v2;
        out_div->v2 = x / in_den;
        x %= in_den;
        x = (x << 32) + in_num->v1;
        out_div->v1 = x / in_den;
        x %= in_den;
        x = (x << 32) + in_num->v0;
        out_div->v0 = x / in_den;
        x %= in_den;

        *out_mod = x;
}

int
main(void)
{
        uint128 x = { 0x12345678, 0x12345678, 0x12345678, 0x12345678 };
        uint128 result;
        uint32_t mod;

        uint128_divmod(&result, &mod, &x, 16);
        fprintf(stdout, "%08"PRIx32" %08"PRIx32" %08"PRIx32" %08"PRIx32" rest %08"PRIx32"\n", result.v3, result.v2, result.v1, result.v0, mod);

        return 0;
}
```

Using this function you can repeatedly compute the mod-36 result, which leads you to the number encoded as base-36.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ with .NET 4 you could always use the [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) class. You could try calling one of the toString overrides to get you to base 36.

Alternatively look at one of the many Big Integer libraries e.g. [Matt McCutchen's C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/index.html) although you might have to look into the [depths of the classes](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/bigint.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/BigUnsignedInABase.cc) to use a custom base such as 36.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
1. It really isn't that hard to divide a byte string by 36. But if you can't be bothered to implement that, you can use base-32 encoding, which would need 26 bytes instead of 25.
2. If you want to be able to read the result over the phone to humans, you absolutely must add a simple checksum to your string, which will cost one or two bytes but will save you a huge amount of 'Chinese whispers' hassle from hard-of-hearing customers.

Comment: Hmm, I did just find this http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html which would ease some of the troubles discussed on another answer.  I hadn't considered a checksum.  I'll look into that. Thanks.